# Cannot find source of PATH variable in zsh

Tags: vim, zsh, path

I wanted to change $PATH and I did not pay attention to shell, so I changed $PATH in .bashrc instead and not in the dotfile for zsh. Now when I wanted to find it and change it, I cannot find any file that contains my current path that I get when run `echo $PATH`.

I tried the following dot files:

etc/zprofile

etc/zshrc

.zsh_sessions

.zprofile

All of these are empty when trying to run vim <file_name>

Comment: Please read [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: You indicated you changed `.bashrc` but then didn’t list it as a file you looked at later. Should we assume you looked in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, I looked in it and it was completely empty. Despite that, I added my path, saved the file, then run source ~/.bashrc and then it works, but ONLY in the current terminal session. If I open a new tab, this file is not sourced anymore

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is not a zsh init file, so that is why it's not working.  You want to change `.zshrc` instead. There is a default value for `$PATH` although I can't find out what it is in the zsh documentation.

Comment: What if I don't have a .zshrc file?

Comment: You can create it. I think I misunderstood your original question, though.